# How to compress/decompress directories using GZipStream?

Tags: c#, .net

I want compress/decompress directories without any dll.

I use this code for compress a file with GzipStream.

```
 public static void Compress(FileInfo fileToCompress)
    {
        using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
        {
            if ((File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden & fileToCompress.Extension != ".gz")
            {
                using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
                {
                    using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                            fileToCompress.Name, fileToCompress.Length.ToString(), compressedFileStream.Length.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I use this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319438/How-to-Compress-Decompress-directories) for compress directory. but don't work for me :(

Comment: In what way does the existing solution not work for you? Seems it should do what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you can't compress an entire directory to a single gz file.  You end up with multiple gz files.

Answer (score 0):

You can package the directory up as a .Tar file and then use gZip on the tar file.
Which would require using a library such as SharpZipLib. You can install the library from the Manage NuGet Packages menu.

```
DirectoryInfo directoryOfFilesToBeTarred = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\tar\start");
FileInfo[] filesInDirectory = directoryOfFilesToBeTarred.GetFiles();
String tarArchiveName = @"c:\tar\mytararchive.tar.gz";
using (Stream targetStream = new GZipOutputStream(File.Create(tarArchiveName)))
{
    using (TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(targetStream, TarBuffer.DefaultBlockFactor))
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fileToBeTarred in filesInDirectory)
        {
            TarEntry entry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToBeTarred.FullName);
            tarArchive.WriteEntry(entry, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Source: 
https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/02/04/packing-and-unpacking-files-using-tar-archives-in-net/

OR

You can zip the directory in pure .NET 3.0. Using SharpZipLib may not be desirable due to the modified GPL license.

First, you will need a reference to WindowsBase.dll.

This code will open or create a zip file, create a directory inside, and place the file in that directory. If you want to zip a folder, possibly containing sub-directories, you could loop through the files in the directory and call this method for each file. Then, you could depth-first search the sub-directories for files, call the method for each of those and pass in the path to create that hierarchy within the zip file.

```
public void AddFileToZip(string zipFilename, string fileToAdd, string destDir)
{
    using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(zipFilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        string destFilename = "." + destDir + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(fileToAdd);
        Uri uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(destFilename, UriKind.Relative));
        if (zip.PartExists(uri))
        {
            zip.DeletePart(uri);
        }
        PackagePart part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "", CompressionOption.Normal);

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileToAdd, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (Stream dest = part.GetStream())
            {
                CopyStream(fileStream, dest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

destDir could be an empty string, which would place the file directly in the zip.

Sources:
https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib

https://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/creating-a-folder-inside-the-zip-file-with-system-io-packaging